# i want to print everything here but %testcase throws error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
testcase = "tc2"

lists = ["1.1.1.1",'%s.tar',"admin","admin","n",None]%testcase

for i in lists:
    cmd = ("%s") %i
    print cmd
```

Throws error because of %testcase
Please show how to execute it because I am new in programming

Comment: BTW, it is strongly  recommended to  use Python 3 (currently 3.6)  instead of Python 2.7. Especially when you are a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put  `%testcase` directly after `'%s.tar'`:

```
testcase = "tc2"

lists = ["1.1.1.1",'%s.tar' %testcase,"admin","admin","n",None]

for i in lists:
    cmd = ("%s") %i
    print(cmd)
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
tc2.tar
admin
admin
n
None
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem. Just click on the check mark (✓) next to the answer. This will toggle it from grayed-out to filled-in.